# Get Data From Website With Web Scraping HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I want to take all questions & images in this website. So I tried this code along with a html dom parser. The multiple div makes an error. How can I get all images and questions of this website?

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.vonvon.me');

$imgname = '';

foreach($html->find('div[class=quiz-item ng-scope]') as $img)
{
    echo $img->src.'<br/>';
    $imgname = $img->src;
}

echo $nimname = $html->find('a.quiz-item ng-scope.div.desc ng-binding')->innertext;
```

Comment: *"it makes a lot of trouble"*?! Give a [mcve] with a real problem description.

Comment: Stick with [PHP/Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte)

Comment: Is it possible to get data from this website, its an anguar js website, help me out. or share something that i can do it.

Comment: Try using Casper js , it is basically for scrapping purpose